# Is there a scale for stickiness of glue?

Tags: adhesion

Non-specialist question stemming from standing in front of a dizzying aisle of consumer adhesives... These differentiate themselves via meaningless superlatives like "serious", "extra" and "ultra". I just wanted to know suitability-for-different-materials and some quantitative measure of "stickiness" :)

*Update:* Could there be a consumer rating system for glue - based on existing professional testing standards?
(Note a rating system doesn't have to be a single numeric measurement in scientific units so can include any scaling/grouping function and include material classfications etc)

Comment: I recall there being two factors for glue: adhesion (stickiness to another material) and cohesion (stickiness to itself). The former factor will vary wildly with the material (consider: "remove grease before applying glue"). The tests would be specific to the material combinations and probably measure the force at which failure of the glue happens.

Comment: ASTM certainly has a range of standards for adhesion and adhesive testing.

Comment: @JonCuster Well, ASTM offers a whole series of documents about glues if alone searching for "adhesives" (https://www.astm.org/Standards/adhesive-standards.html) including quantificative comparative assessments (e.g. https://www.astm.org/Standards/D5649.htm states "inch-pound units" in its preview as standard unit).  Given the multiple materials  (paper, wood, polymers, metals, biomaterials, etc. pp.) and applications possible, a rather broad question indeed.